# understanding assembly: -O2 if branching

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly

I just tried out a simple C program using an if statement and analyzed its assembly. However, its behavior differs a lot when -O2 flag is used for compilation.

The C code for the same is :-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a;

    if(a<0) {
        printf("A is less than 0\n");
    }
}
```

And the corresponding assembly is:-

```
main:
    push    %ebp
    mov %ebp, %esp
    sub %esp, 8
    and %esp, -16
    sub %esp, 16
    test    %eax, %eax
    js  .L4
    leave
    ret
    .p2align 4,,15
.L4:
    sub %esp, 12
    push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    puts
    add %esp, 16
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 3.4.6"
```

I read that the `test` instruction basically just performs the logical AND of the two operands. I also read that the `js` instruction performs a jump when there is a change in sign in the previous instruction. So, `test`ing eax with eax would give `0` or `1` and the jump would depend on this.

I fail to understand how it is being used here for branching.
Could someone explain how this works?

Comment: A good compiler should optimize the whole program to nothing since it has undefined behavior (use of an uninitialized variable). Or, if `a` were initialized, it should optimize out the conditional based on the value of `a`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JS doesn't jump when there is a change in sign, it jumps if the sign flag is 1.

The sign bit is on if the result of the last operation was negative(negative numbers in 2's compliment have the most significant bit in 1).

So if the AND operation was between two negative integers(-1 & -1) the last bit will be 1(sign flag), so the jump is taken. In case the numbers were positive the last bit would be 0, the jump won't be taken.

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know what you expect, but your program has undefined behavior since `a` is not initialized. So the assembler output could be literally anything.

Comment: Does the whole program get undefined just because `a`'s value is undefined? I assumed it would use whatever was on the stack at invocation.

Comment: The program's output could be the printf or it could be nothing, but why would the compiler's output be anything?

Comment: In theory the output could be anything, but no real world compiler will output nonsense.

Comment: @nmichaels: the program’s *behaviour* is undefined, yes. That of the whole program. For example, the optimizer could very well conclude that `a` is never written to, hence its value is undefined, hence any subsequent usage of `a` can be elided. That would be a completely valid optimization.

Comment: @nmichaels: the standard doesn't require that there is anything on the stack at invocation. The storage for this uninitialized `a` is permitted to be backed not by RAM, but by a yawning void of chaos, touching which calls an Elder Horror into the world. Or, more realistically, on some architectures the memory could contain a trap representation which causes the hardware to throw a fault when it's loaded into an int register. To permit both of these (and especially the second), behavior of the program is undefined. x86 doesn't need quite this much freedom, but it's there in the standard.

Comment: instead of using main() which has a well known prototype, make it something like void fun ( int a ), remove the local variable and avoid this problem.  And the optimizer wont have to have a compiler specific opinion as to whether or not to remove the if, it will stay there.

Comment: @dwelch, yes, *probably* the assembler output would be the same. Only that you can never be sure, and I think that the least that we can ask for is that such a question has a well defined test program that compiles without warnings. What I really don't understand is that someone seems to have downvoted my answer...

Comment: wasnt me, I upvoted your answer, and gave you an upvote on the last comment for good measure.  Because the sample code was questionable who knows what a compiler would do, my comment was in support of your answer.  An important part of understanding assembler by writing and compiling C to assembler, is to be crystal clear about the C that you are writing, otherwise the compiler will do what appears to be strange things from time to time.  To save on opcodes this compiler was trained with an interesting solution.  Upvoted SanSS too..

Comment: @dwelch, didn't wanted to suggest that, should have put that in a different comment, sorry. Also I don't think that my ego does depend too much on obtaining points, here, but I was just surprised that someone could do this :)

Answer (score 3):

The Intel manuals are good for this.  This is what it documents for the TEST instruction:

[image]

SF is the sign flag, the one that's tested by the JS opcode.  It is set to the most significant bit of eax here, the sign bit.  The jump is thus taken when eax contains a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

If `eax` is negative, the flags will indicate that after the `test` instruction and the jump will be taken. That pushes the PC to `.L4` which does the printing. Otherwise, we leave.

Answer (score 2):

`test eax, eax` will set zero flag if eax = 0

js instruction will check the sign flag basically (a<0)

Comment: `test` sets *all* of the arithmetic flags, not just the zero flag.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like when you specify -O2, the compiler is putting your "int a" into a register for speed optimization.

Since you never initialize 'int a', the assembly does not show anything written to eax and it instead has the value that was last assigned to it.

The other answers explain how test is working as a branching mechanism.